# How can I compile code directly that was originally written in code::blocks

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, codeblocks

I need to compile code someone gave me, which they wrote in code::blocks. I know code::blocks uses gcc, but what is the specific format for the command(s) it uses to do so? Because of various circumstances, I can't use code::blocks myself for this, and I'm too rusty at compiling C/C++ to figure it out from the code.

Comment: Isn't there a Makefile so you can run `make`?

Comment: The GCC command to compile some C++ unit (warnings enabled) is `g++ -Wall -c unitname.cpp`. Then you link the units with `g++ -o appname.exe unit1name.o unit2name.o`. But this will work only if the project itself doesn't use any specific options (like preprocessor defines). I have no idea how to extract those special options from a Code::Blocks project.

Answer (score 2):

check out this - [cbp2make - makefile generation tool](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,13675.0.html)

haven't used it, just assumed it should exist

Answer (score 1):

i imagine code blocks has a place for compilation and linking options, so i guess you could ask him what they are

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to insert a small stub named `gcc` that records all its arguments and then forwards to the real GCC. This is fairly easy with a shell script.